# Pull PDF out of database blob field and save within public/assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, paperclip

I have a `blob` column in a table that I know represents pdf documents.  I am attempting to write a migration that rips out the pdf documents from that `blob` field, and saves the actual pdf documents within public/assets.  I am using [paperclip](https://rubygems.org/gems/paperclip) for attachments.

Here is the error I am getting:

> StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled: "\xC4" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8

Here is my script:

```
class AddSomeAttachments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up

    SomeModel.all.each do |something|
      if something.data.present?
        FileUtils.mkdir_p(Rails.root.join('public', 'assets', 'some_models', 'attachment1', "#{something.id}" ))
      end
    end

    SomeModel.all.each do |something|
      if something.data.present?
        File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'assets', 'some_models', 'attachment1', "#{something.id}", "#{something.attachment1_file_name}"), "w+") do |file|
          file << something.data
        end
      end
    end

  end

  def down
    raise "do not migrate down"
  end
end
```

I did look at [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797469/xc4-from-ascii-8bit-to-utf-8-when-running-rake-dbmigrate-on-heroku) which asked about the same error message. I did attempt adding `encoding: UTF-8` at the top of the file but that did not do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing a binary file:

```
File.open(filename, 'wb') do |file|
```

Comment: yup, that was the problem.  Thanks!